# Is face detection possible on iPad camera without showing camera feed?

Tags: ipad, ios5, face-detection, core-image

I am creating an iPad app that is to be used in a public kiosk, and am playing with different ways of knowing when a user is present, has gone away or a new user has come along. I wondered therefore if this would be possible using a iOS 5 Core Image detection script, but I need to be able to use the camera feed without it actually showing the user. Is this in any way possible?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I am no longer working on this project, however I would still be intrigued to know if anyone finds an answer!

Comment: I actually did it. So I'll post an answer later